# Vagrant Virtualbox VMs getting "kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s"

Tags: linux-kernel, centos7, watchdog, nmi

I am running CentOS VMs in Virtualbox using Vagrant on a Windows PC.
I've done this for 2 years without issue (initially CentOS 6 then CentOS 7), but in the last few months, I notice my VMs to start locking up frequently. And outputs these types of messages when it gets going again

```
Message from syslogd@node1 at Jan 25 17:51:55 ...
 kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [C1 CompilerThre:7243]
```

repeated a number of times.

I think what is happening is the NMI watchdog is waiting for an interrupt, and has a set time to receive, but if a process is holding things up and it doesn't get this interrupt it assumes something has gone wrong and initials a kernel panic, locking things up for a bit.

I've come across options for increasing the `kernel.watchdog_thresh=30` in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` or disabling the NMI watchdog altogether.
Should I consider trying one of these?
Is the watchdog too eager, or might I have some underlying issue? there's not much on my VMs when this happens.

Comment: I have similar issue with my setup. Didn't have issue with hp laptop but "better" dell laptop gets it all the time.  I have found if it seems frozen I can ssh from another bash terminal and it will like kick start it.

Comment: @Travis I have found similar if I open up another terminal it kick starts it, but sometimes it takes a while.

Comment: For me it also often un-freezes when I randomly click around in the VirtualBox Manger window.

Comment: Same issue here. seams to be related to docker command, but not for sure.